# In angular application, while inspecting an element via chrome dev tool, why do I not see pure html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, google-chrome-devtools

My question is basically what the title says:

If browser do not understand angular, why am I seeing angular while inspecting element in spite of using AOT (no angular compiler in the browser)?

Is there anyway to see the DOM with pure html elements?

E.g. 
Why do I see `<k-dialog>` element, when using kendo dialog which is angular component? Are these elements simply ignored or are they `div` under the hood?

[image]

Comment: I see classes and comments and attributes that belong to Angular when I inspect elements of my Angular app, but it's still all standard DOM elements that I'm see. No *ngIf or *ngFor, for example. Can you show us an example of what you're seeing that you don't think is "pure"?

Comment: @kshetline updated question.

Comment: Looks like HTML to me, are you saying the custom tags/element are not valid HTML?

Comment: @epascarello, Ok, so even it is a valid HTML, what happens to it during rendering? Is it a containing "div" element or simply ignored?

Comment: inspect it and see what it says in the console.

Comment: @epascarello, I do not know what do you mean? I used "Use in console" in firefox and it shows the same node

Comment: Click on one of the `kendo-dialog-*` elements and look at the right pane of the Elements tab. You'll see the Styles tab is selected by default, and from that, should be able to tell how (if at all) it is styled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is standard HTML, because HTML5 allows custom elements:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: Are these custom elements rendered anyway or simply ignored by the browser?

Comment: My impression (and this is just my impression) is that they act very much like either a span or a div, depending on the CSS properties you assign to them.